# Convert 32 bit GDI bitmap to Grayscale by manipulating bmBits

Tags: c, casting, char, autohotkey, grayscale

I program only on windows (AutoHotkey) and mainly use its win32 api.
I want to convert a GDI Bitmap (32bit DIB) to grayscale.
I use [GetObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) to obtain a [BITMAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmap) structure and pass bmBITS and it size to following function

```
int ToGrayscale(unsigned char * s, int n)
{
  float b, g, r, y;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
  {
       b = (float) s[i+0];
       g = (float) s[i+1];
       r = (float) s[i+2];
     y = (0.299 * r) + (0.587 * g) + (0.114 * b);
     s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = (unsigned char)y;
  }
return 1;
}
```

The above is the full code. I compile it to an .obj with Pelles C, extract the machine code from .obj
and call/use that machine code from AutoHotkey language.

The machine code when called gives me access violation error.

```
s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = 0;
```

works fine and fills the image to black, but I want to convert the pixels with y, the grayscale value.
What is the correct way of doing this?.

I'm not sure if I've provided enough info. Please ask/suggest and I will update it.

EDIT 1:
I added one more working function ToBlack() to the c file.

```
int ToBlack(unsigned char * s, int n)
{
  for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
  {
     s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = 0;
  }
return 1;
}

int ToGrayscale(unsigned char * s, int n)
{
  float b, g, r, y;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
  {
       b = (float) s[i+0];
       g = (float) s[i+1];
       r = (float) s[i+2];
     y = (0.299 * r) + (0.587 * g) + (0.114 * b);
     s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = (unsigned char)y;
  }
return 1;
}
```

The source bitmap is a 2x2 32bit opaque bitmap with single ARGB color FFAABBCC
The bmBITS size is 16 bytes and the hex representation of data is
**CCBBAAFFCCBBAAFFCCBBAAFFCCBBAAFF**

ToBlack() works fine and when I inspect bmBITS after running the machine code,
I get following results - correctly.

ToBlack(bmBITS, 16) Result: **000000FF000000FF000000FF000000FF**

ToBlack(bmBITS, 12) Result: **000000FF000000FF000000FFCCBBAAFF**

ToBlack(bmBITS, 8)  Result: **000000FF000000FFCCBBAAFFCCBBAAFF**

ToBlack(bmBITS, 4)  Result: **000000FFCCBBAAFFCCBBAAFFCCBBAAFF**

With ToGrayscale(bmBITS, 16) data is unchanged.
I'm guessing that the crash is occurring when y is being assigned.

Comment: I assume `n` is the number of pixels, whereas `i` iterates over each color byte. Then it should be `i<(n/4)`

Comment: Thanks for reply.
n is the byte size of bmBITS.
I've added one more function to .c file to illustrate my problem.
Please read the edited post.

Comment: `bmBits` is defined as _"Pointer to the location of the bit values for the bitmap. The bmBits member must be a long pointer to an array of character (1-byte) values."_ That object has size `bmHeight * bmWidthBytes` bytes. Then that is `n`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source for the *Access violation error*.
The machine code isn't portable.
For the following c code

```
int ToGrayscale(unsigned char * s, int n)
{
  float b, g, r, y;
  for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
  {
       b = (float) s[i+0];
       g = (float) s[i+1];
       r = (float) s[i+2];
     y = (0.299 * r) + (0.587 * g) + (0.114 * b);
     s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = (unsigned char)y;
  }
return 1;
}
```

the .obj dump is as follows:

```
Dump of D:\AhkScripts\AHK-003\ToGrayscale.obj

File type: OBJ


_ToGrayscale:
  [00000000] 55                     push              ebp
  [00000001] 89E5                   mov               ebp,esp
  [00000003] 83EC10                 sub               esp,10
  [00000006] 56                     push              esi
  [00000007] 8B5508                 mov               edx,dword ptr [ebp+8]
  [0000000A] 8B4D0C                 mov               ecx,dword ptr [ebp+C]
  [0000000D] 85C9                   test              ecx,ecx
  [0000000F] 7E6C                   jle               0000007D
  [00000011] 31F6                   xor               esi,esi
  [00000013] 0FB60432               movzx             eax,byte ptr [edx+esi]
  [00000017] 50                     push              eax
  [00000018] DB0424                 fild              dword ptr [esp]
  [0000001B] 58                     pop               eax
  [0000001C] D95DFC                 fstp              dword ptr [ebp-4]
  [0000001F] 0FB6443201             movzx             eax,byte ptr [edx+esi+1]
  [00000024] 50                     push              eax
  [00000025] DB0424                 fild              dword ptr [esp]
  [00000028] 58                     pop               eax
  [00000029] D95DF8                 fstp              dword ptr [ebp-8]
  [0000002C] 0FB6443202             movzx             eax,byte ptr [edx+esi+2]
  [00000031] 50                     push              eax
  [00000032] DB0424                 fild              dword ptr [esp]
  [00000035] 58                     pop               eax
  [00000036] D95DF4                 fstp              dword ptr [ebp-C]
  [00000039] D945F4                 fld               dword ptr [ebp-C]
  [0000003C] DC0D00000000           fmul              qword ptr [@37]
  [00000042] D945F8                 fld               dword ptr [ebp-8]
  [00000045] DC0D00000000           fmul              qword ptr [@38]
  [0000004B] DEC1                   faddp             st(1),st
  [0000004D] D945FC                 fld               dword ptr [ebp-4]
  [00000050] DC0D00000000           fmul              qword ptr [@39]
  [00000056] DEC1                   faddp             st(1),st
  [00000058] D95DF0                 fstp              dword ptr [ebp-10]
  [0000005B] D945F0                 fld               dword ptr [ebp-10]
  [0000005E] E800000000             call              ___ftouc
  [00000063] 88443202               mov               byte ptr [edx+esi+2],al
  [00000067] D945F0                 fld               dword ptr [ebp-10]
  [0000006A] E800000000             call              ___ftouc
  [0000006F] 88443201               mov               byte ptr [edx+esi+1],al
  [00000073] 880432                 mov               byte ptr [edx+esi],al
  [00000076] 83C604                 add               esi,4
  [00000079] 39CE                   cmp               esi,ecx
  [0000007B] 7C96                   jl                00000013
  [0000007D] B801000000             mov               eax,1
  [00000082] 5E                     pop               esi
  [00000083] 89EC                   mov               esp,ebp
  [00000085] 5D                     pop               ebp
  [00000086] C3                     ret               

SUMMARY
      28 .drectve
      18 .rdata
      87 .text
```

There seems to be calls to a non-existent function named **___ftouc** which I suppose
is **Float to Unsigned Char**, and it will be available only when linked.
*(Please correct me if I'm wrong)*

**Solution?** Do the the math in a way that wouldn't require type casting.
The following code works just fine in x86 / x64.

```
void ToGrayscale(unsigned char * s, int n)
{
  for (int i=0; i<n; i+=4)
     s[i+0] = s[i+1] = s[i+2] = ( (s[i+0]*114) + (s[i+1]*587) + (s[i+2]*299) ) / 1000;
}
```